# Getline behavior with printf in loop

Tags: c, loops, printf, posix, getline

Why do I need to hit enter twice to get the current directory to change? I notice that if I change the location of the printf statement in the loop, the behavior changes. I don't understand why that is.

Working code for you below. It compiles on a Ubuntu system. It works fairly minimally. Most of it is usage from man-pages.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h> // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html
int main() {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t linecap = 0;
    ssize_t linelen;
    while ((linelen = getline(&line, &linecap, stdin)) > 0) {
        char * buf = NULL;
        size_t size = 1000;
        char * s = getcwd(buf, size);
        printf("%s# ", s);
        *(line+linelen-1) = '\0';
        chdir(&line[3]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't get the output to the program, which I show below (first, I need to hit enter once to get the prompt -- that's okay and intended for this example).

```
/path/to/dir# cd ..
/path/to/dir# 
/path/to#
```

Comment: what is "something"? variable `s` is never used?

Comment: What is `getline`? It is non-standard

Comment: I edited the typo. Something, e.g., could be a system call to chdir(2).

Comment: The code does not make sense, please include what is `something`, [mcve]

Comment: I added a comment in the code to address what getline(3) is. I'll change the code shortly to use chdir(2) instead of 'something'...

Comment: Thanks, updated the tag description.

Comment: @Olaf probably the POSIX function `getline`

Comment: @user3773048 make sure to post a MCVE including everything necessary for someone else to reproduce the problem, don't just make a couple of changes

Comment: @mm: yes, I edited the tag already, just waiting for approval by someone with >= 20k reps ... ;-).

Comment: I just created working code for this question. Compiles and does what I wanted to show to ask. Should I edit this question or create a new one?

Comment: I updated the question for you guys. I'd appreciate something productive, other than just down-voting me in the time it took me to rewrite the question...

Comment: @t0mm13b I followed your advice and updated the question.

Comment: @M.M I updated the question as a MCVE, as you and t0mm13b suggested.

Comment: @Olaf I did use the POSIX getline. You can see more about it from man7.org. I also updated my question so you could also compile and run it on a machine.

Comment: @user3773048: Please read may last comments! I edited your tags to make clear it requires POSIX-API

Comment: @Olaf Ok, makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop does the following logic:

- Wait for user input
- Print the current directory
- Change the current directory

So each time you enter user input, it will show the old directory, change directory (with no visible output) and then wait for new input.  This is indeed what your sample output shows.

To get your desired behaviour, move the `getcwd` and display down to below the `chdir` call.

Note that if the person subsequently enters a string shorter than 3 (e.g. they press Enter again, I did while testing and so did you) you go on to call `chdir(&line[3]);` anyway, causing undesired results (possibly UB) since this is past the end of the string.  On my system it repeated the `chdir("..")`.  To fix this , you should probably check `linelen >= 3` (and also that it did actually start with `cd`), and not call `chdir` if not.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, I made it very minimal on purpose, but I guess my output was lucky based on my env. I see. Of course, it's simply off by one iteration of the loop. This was a simple loop question... Guess I could've made my code more minimalistic haha.